# Cognito SDK, authenticate user using a federated (third-party) identity provider

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm trying to authenticate a third-partry identity provider (OKTA) user using the cognito SDK, I have the user defined both in a Congito pool and in OKTA (IdP) and the users are linked:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/TCognitoIdentityProviderClient.html

> To authenticate users from third-party identity providers (IdPs) in
> this API, you can link IdP users to native user profiles.

Using the internal link [(How to link users)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation-consolidate-users.html), I have succefully linked the users using AdminLinkProviderForUser.

I have also set a and API client and a hosted UI for OKTA and I am able to login both Cognito user and OKTA using the hosted UI:
[image]

However my issue is when trying to authenticate with the cognito .net SDK, i'm only able to authenticate using the Cogntio user credentials but not with the OKTA identiy provider user credentials, i'm not sure how to do this and I have not found a working example, this is my code:

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool("us-east-1_-----hbW", "-------------jduo", provider);
CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("test-user", "------------jduo", userPool, provider,
    clientSecret: "------------------9aecc8");

InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest
{
    Password = "hellohello1",
};

AuthFlowResponse authResponse;
try
{
    authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}

return authResponse?.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

I am using the OKTA credentials but keep getting incorrect username or password.